# Remove then Query fails in JPA (deleted entity passed to persist)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, seam

I have two entitys MobeeCustomer and CustomerRegion i want to remove the object from CustomerRegion first Im put join Coloumn in CustomerRegion is null then  Remove the Object
from the entityManager but Iam getting Exception

MobeeCustomer:

> ```
>   public class MobeeCustomer implements Serialization{
>
>   private Long id;
>
>   private String custName;
>
>   private String Address;
>
>   private String phoneNo; 
>
>   private Set<CustomerRegion> customerRegion = new HashSet<CustomerRegion>(0);
>
>
>   @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE },
>    fetch =    FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mobeeCustomer")     
>    public Set<CustomerRegion> getCustomerRegion() { 
>     return CustomerRegion;  
>      }
>
>   public void setCustomerRegion(Set<CustomerRegion> customerRegion) {
>       CustomerRegion = customerRegion;    
>     }
>
>   }
> ```

CustomerRegion

```
  public class CustomerRegion implements Serializable{

private Long id;

private String custName;

private String description;

private String createdBy;
private Date createdOn;

private String updatedBy;
private Date updatedOn;
   private MobeeCustomer mobeeCustomer;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MOBEE_CUSTOMER")
public MobeeCustomer getMobeeCustomer() {
    return mobeeCustomer;
}
public void setMobeeCustomer(MobeeCustomer mobeeCustomer) {
    this.mobeeCustomer = mobeeCustomer;
}


   }
```

sample code:

```
   if (doUpdateRegion.getStatus().equals(UserOperations.DELETE.getType())) {

custEntity = getEntityManager().find(CustomerRegion.class,doUpdateRegion.getId());


      BeanUtils.copyProperties(custEntity, doUpdateRegion);

deletedRegionsList.add(custEntity);



}


  for (CustomerRegion region : deletedRegionList) {


            region.setMobeeCustomer(null);
      getEntityManager().remove(region);
}







StackTrace:

please suggest me how to remove the CustomerRegion Object I  am getting Exception

  javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist:          [com.manam.mobee.persist.entity.CustomerRegion#<null>]
15:46:34,614 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:613)
15:46:34,614 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:299)
15:46:34,614 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerProxy.flush(EntityManagerProxy.java:92)
15:46:34,614 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityHome.update(EntityHome.java:64)
```

Comment: How you obtain the list?

Comment: I see that you are new in stackoverflow, perhaps you can [look at the FAQ to see how to upvote and accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove an entity that has no `id`. Thus the entity manager cannot locate it in the DB. This is call a detached entity.

Try retrieve the list of regions from the DB before delete them.

If you did, then This looks like a `transaction` problem. You are outside a transaction and thus the entity is detached from the session. Try do it all in the same transaction and don't call `entityManager.remove()`, just remove from the collection the item and  the flush will be automatic  when   you close the transaction and commit.

For example with `Spring`

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void deleteRegions(Set<CustomerRegion> deletedRegionList){
    revion.getMobeeCustomer().getCusotmerRegion.removeAll(deletedRegionList);
}
```

If that method ends the transaction it will commit. All modifications Hibernate/JPA ends calls a flush, which sync the state of the memory with the DB.

Comment: How is he going to delete the entity from the database if he doesn't call remove?

Comment: because when the transaction ends all modifications JPA calls a flush, which sync the state of the memory with the DB. When those entities becomes orphan, if the configuration is the appropriate the object will be deleted

Comment: In CustomerRegion, mobeeCustomer can be null and the id is a long. It seems to me like CustomerRegion can exists without a MobeeCustomer, so they would not become orphans.

Comment: then those won't be deleted, only the relation

Comment: Yes, the problem is that he seems to want to delete one CustomerRegion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that there is still a reference to CustomerRegion in MobeeCustomer. If that is the problem, this should fix it:

```
for (CustomerRegion region : deletedRegionList) {
      region.getMobeeCustomer().getCustomerRegion().remove(region);
      getEntityManager().remove(region);
}
```